# Visual studio 2022 crash windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2022, git-clone

Visual studio 2022 crash windows on upload Wen try clone a git

Wen I try clone fro git, using VS2022 it during the upload crash windows, restarting it. I really don't know what to do, already reinstalled git, and repaired VS2022. Although I tryed with Visual Studio 2019, and it did well, and using gitUI did well to. So the problem is in version 2022. Any help / ideas I appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

It was MB / CPU issue, they have been replaced by the brand. after i format, it start rebooting random wen seeing videos online, it didnt reboot only wen i was playing some game.